# How can i Kill a process after every second?

Tags: android, process, kill-process

how can i kill a process after every second.i want to set a timer which will check every second if the process is been started and keep killing that particular process by its package name

Comment: For the love of god, why would you do this? Besides the ridiculous amount of battery drain you're going to cause running your app continuously every second, I don't believe you're able to kill processes which are not your own any more without a system signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void appKiller() {
String nameOfProcess = "location";
ActivityManager  manager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfProcesses =  manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : listOfProcesses)
{
    if (process.processName.contains(nameOfProcess))
{
    // Ends the app
    manager.killBackgroundProcesses(process.processName);
    break;
}}
```

//Using timer call to appKiller as below.

```
timer = new Timer("killTimer");
timer.schedule(oTimer, 1000 * 1l,   1000 * 1l );
private TimerTask oTimer = new TimerTask() {
    private void doWork() {
        try {
            appKiller();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
            @Override
    public void run() {

        doWork();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you should not kill thread.

What you can do is

```
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    //this you should do when you declare your thread after creating thread object.
    thread.setDaemon(true);
```

// TO KILL YOUR THREAD USE THIS

```
thread.interrupt();
thread = null;
```

To kill other application process use

```
    android.os.Process.killProcess(thread_id);
```

Comment: help is appreciated but i dont want to kill my own process or thread i want to perform this action to kill other apps and other processesss